# Parsing OpenXML with multiple elements of the same name based on attribute

Tags: sql, openxml

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013036/parsing-openxml-with-multiple-elements-of-the-same-name) but I need to parse based on specific attribute. How do you select only one of the elements with the same name based on the attribute value?

```
DECLARE @doc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @doc OUTPUT, N'
<rootnode>
  <group>
    <id>1</id>
     <anothernode lang="de">first string</anothernode>
     <anothernode lang="en">second string</anothernode>
  </group>
  <group>
    <id>1</id>
     <anothernode lang="en">I</anothernode>
     <anothernode lang="de">Ich</anothernode>
  </group>
</rootnode>'

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@doc, 'rootnode/group')
WITH
(
    id int 'id',
    anothernode  varchar(30) 'anothernode'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @doc
```

Result is:

```
1   first string
2   Ich
```

And I need:

```
1   second string
2   I
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hacking I found that I can get correct result by doing following SELECT:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@doc, 'rootnode/group')
WITH
(
    id int 'id',
    anothernode  varchar(30) 'anothernode[@lang="en"]'
)
```

Result is:

```
1   second string
2   I
```

Main difference is `[@lang="en"]`, which selects specific attribute value.